# Receiving Firebase autoId in tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `firebase` structure that looks like this:
[image]

The blue one is named feedPosts, the green one is the userId, the one without color is the autoId firebase creates for appending data and the orange one says **content: "users post string is here"**.

My problem is that I do not know how to get the `firebase` autoId so that I can show what the user have posted in my `tableViewController`. I need to append data to the userId so that the user can post several posts - I just do not know how to get the key in a `tableViewController`. Help me?

Comment: Do you know beforehand whats in that autoID? Or else it would be stupid to retrieve the entire data, loop through each autoID and retrieve a single data node.

Comment: No I do not know beforehand what the autoID is.. Can you give me an example to work with?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to change your structure to match the data you are trying to get. Here's what you have now

```
feedPosts
   -fbUserId0
     -autoIdForThisPost1
        content: "users post string is here"
   -fbUserId1
     -autoIdForThisPost1
        content: "users post string is here"
```

change it to this

```
feedPosts
   -autoIdForThisPost0
      post_by_uid: "-fbUserId0"
      content: "users post string is here"
   -autoIdForThisPost1
      post_by_uid: "-fbUserId1"
      content: "users post string is here"
```

Then you can query for all of the posts by -fbUserId1. That will return each post node which will contain the content as well as the KEY of the post being the autoId.

This is also expandable as you could also store for example, a timestamp about the post, or perhaps even what post this is in response to.

Another advantage is that is makes the whole structure flatter (flatter is better! very important in Firebase) and is more query-able.

Comment: I'm gonna try to do that - it sounds like the best solution! How do I query for the userId?

Comment: @D.Finna Look at the guide here [Retrieving Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data) and in the Filtering Data section take a look at queryEqualToValue.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like something I could use :-) I will definately look at that!

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is something like this:-

```
foodItems{
      uid1 :{
          autoID1 :{
                content : "This is a String"
         }
      }
    }
```

To retrieve the autoID which contains the **`content : "This is a String"`**

**Swift 2.3**

```
   let parentRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("foodItems/\(FIRAuth().auth()!.currentUser!.uid)").queryOrderedByChild("content").queryEqualToValue("This is a String")

     parentRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock:{(snap) in 

      if let snapContainingContent = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

         for each in snapContainingContent{
             print(each.0)//your autoID
             print(each.1)//your content String
             if let autoDict = each.1 as? NSDictionary{

                   print(autoDict["content"]!)
                   print(autoDict.allKeys(for: "This is a String")[0])


                }
            }

       }

 })
```

**Swift 3**

```
let parentRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts/foodItems/uid1").queryOrdered(byChild: "content").queryEqual(toValue: "This is a String")

    parentRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:{(snap) in

        if let snapContainingContent = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapContainingContent{
                print(each.0)//your autoID
                print(each.1)//your content String
                if let autoDict = each.1 as? NSDictionary{

                   print(autoDict["content"]!)
                   print(autoDict.allKeys(for: "This is a String")[0])
                }

            }

        }

    })
```

Comment: But that would only show me that specific part of the code? I want to show all content: "with string" - isn't that possible?

Comment: I have edited my answer... That's the best you gonna get with autoID's. Alternative would be to loop over the entire node to search for a particular content in that child node :)Happy Coding